# C#, EF: Map [NotMapped] value from Sql Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework. I currently have an attribute that is labeled `[NotMapped]` in my model class. I'm also using a query to bring back that value (from a view, which is why it's not mapped).

```
var list = context.Database
                  .SqlQuery<SomeModel>("SELECT NonMappedField, anotherfield FROM SomeView")
                  .ToList()
```

Is there a way I can hint to C# that for this instance, it should map the column from the raw query to my models?

I would have more things showing what I've tried, but I don't have the slightest clue of what to do next, other than build my own mapper and that seems like a very brittle solution.

**Possible X/Y Problem:**

My a data model has a Parent/Child relationship.  The Child can be a child of multiple models,necessitating the use of a join table ParentChildJoin.  When I do

```
context.Database.Parent.Where...Include( n => n.Children ).ToList();
```

I run into query timeouts for a pathetically small number of rows.  So I had the bright idea of joining the ParentChildJoin table with the Child table in a View and retrieving the children that way.  This works, but I need some way to map the retrieved Child objects to their Parent.

This is where the NotMapped field comes in.  I can create a NonMapped field on my model, and then when I retrieve from my View, I can store the ParentId there. From there, I can associate the Child objects with the correct parent.

So that's how I go here.

Comment: "from a View', that sounds like a terrible idea. Just remove the `[NotMapped]` and use DTOs/ViewModels

Comment: Not sure what you mean by mapped and non-mapped field. Are you trying to make your program smart enough to know what fields to select from a table and load the results into a list?

Comment: @David.Warwick "not mapped" means that Entity Framework will not select that value nor update it in the database

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I've edited my post about why and how I arrived at using a View.

Answer (score 0):

Either the field is mapped or it isn't, you can't have it both ways!

Take a look at AutoMapper and the AutoMapperEF extension.  The EF extension is clever enough to realise that a model that only has a selection of fields from a query will only have those fields in the generated `SELECT`.  You could have several different models for the same query, each only returning the fields required for that model.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do (without changing model) is to concatenate `NonMappedField+"_"+anotherfield` as `anotherfield` before load.

After FromSql load, you can split `NonMappedField` and `anotherfield` back.

```
var query = "SELECT [Id], CONVERT(VARCHAR(1024),[NonMappedField]+'|'+[anotherfield]) AS [anotherfield] FROM myView";
var list = _context.SomeModels.FromSql(query)
           .Select(i => new SomeModel { 
               Id = i.Id, 
               NonMappedField = i.anotherfield.Substring(0, i.anotherfield.IndexOf('|')), 
               anotherfield = i.anotherfield.Substring(i.anotherfield.IndexOf('|')+1)   
           }).ToList();
```